# How to hide endpoint in swagger depending on environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have a Controller that is named TestController which is used to perform some tests. I would like to hide that controller whenever i'm in production but not when running in stage or local.
The endpoints could still be used, but i would like to hide all endpoint under test.

[image: Picture of how it looks today]

Comment: You could use a preprocessor directive over the entire controller class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could define a conditional depending on build type and use a preprocessor  directive over your entire test controller class.That means your class will not even get translated into bytecode when in production :
You can check the MSDN official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

Basically in order to do this you need to go to:
**`Solution Explorer -> Right Click [Project Name] -> Properties -> Build`** 
Set your configuration (upper left side) e.g `Debug` and define your conditional  compilation symbol e.g `DEBUGSYMBOL` .

[image]

Now you can use it in your code like this:

```
#if DEBUGSYMBOL
         public class TestController{
         }
#endif
```

This code will get written to binary and executed only if your Conditional  Symbol is present in the target configuration.In your case you want `DEBUGSYMBOL` to be defined only in `Debug`.

**P.S** You can define these kind of conditional Symbols in any of your configurations.

Comment: Is it possible to do #if ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT == 'Production' i would like to check for production ?

Comment: Check my response

Comment: For production use `_env.IsProduction()` by injecting `IHostingEnvironment env`

Comment: checkout this class https://github.com/Boriszn/DeviceManager.Api/blob/master/src/DeviceManager.Api/Startup.cs

Comment: This solution with symbol only work if i debug the environment right ? 
But what if we have 3 environments. Dev, Stage and prod. Dev is running locally and stage and prod is running on servers. I would like to hide it only on prod environment. Is that possible otherwise i think i will use the debug solution

Comment: No its not only for debug.You can define conditionals in any of your  build types.You can define 3 build types and in each of them define a conditional  variable.Then in your code you use `#if DEBUG [....code ....] #endif` , `#if PROD [...code...] #endif` , `#if STAGE [...code...] #endif`.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that it won't work if you have a single build, but are deploying it to different environments.